# Como subir un texto de summernote a mysql

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Tengo un texto en `javascript` con la libreria `summernote` pero no se como subirlo a `mysql` a continuación esta el código que tengo

```html
<?php
 
 session_start();
 if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status']) 
    {
        header("location: login.php"); 
        exit;                                              
        }


 
 require_once ("config/db.php");
 require_once ("config/conexion.php");
  
 $active_ticket="active"; 
 $title="Prestamos | Simple Stock";
    $Nticket= $_GET['Nticket'];
    $incidencia= $_GET['incidencia'];
    $tema= $_GET['tema'];
    $detalle= $_GET['detalle'];
    $firstname= $_GET['firstname'];




     if(isset($_POST["respuesta"]))
               $respuesta = $_POST["respuesta"];
            else
                $respuesta =NULL;
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE incidencia = '" . $incidencia . "' OR tema = '" . $tema . "';";
                $query_check_incidencia = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO ticket (respuesta) VALUE('".$respuesta."');";
           
                    $query_new_incidencia_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);





       ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <title>Summernote</title>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.8/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.8/summernote.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <?php include("head.php");
    include("navbarhelp.php");?>
    
    <div class="subject">Asunto:<strong><?php echo $tema; ?></strong></div>
    <div id="ticketThread">
    <table class="thread-entry message" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1"width="800" boder="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th>
            <div>
                <span class="textra"></span>
                <span><?php echo $firstname; ?></span>
                </div>    
            </th>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="thread-body"><div><?php echo $detalle ?></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="thread-entry response" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="800" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th>
                <div>
                Respuesta <span class="textra"></span>
                <span></span>
                </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr><br>
                <td class="thread-body"><br><div><?php echo $respuesta?><br></div></td></tr>
            </tbody></table></div>
          
    <form action="respuestas.php?Nticket=<?php echo $Nticket?>&incidencia=<?
      =$incidencia?>&tema=<?=$tema?>&detalle=<?=$detalle?>&firstname=<?
     =$firstname?>" method="post"> 
    <div id="summernote"></div>
      
   <button type="submit" id="respuesta" name="submit" 
           value="1">Responder</button>
  </form>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#summernote').summernote();

    
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El mandar el contenido de summernote tal y como viene no es posible tomarlo a tu controller, antes de enviar tendrás que trabajar con las funciones **encode** de javascript para poder enviarlas; y de igual forma para cargarlas.

```
//tomar el contenido
encodeURIComponent(summnernote.contenido);
//cargar el contenido
decodeURIComponent(mysql.contenido);
```

En pocas palabras, guardaras el [encodeURI](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp) de tu summernote.